# How can I write meta tag when website has javascript like polymer?

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, meta-tags

I have written a meta tag in the `head` of each page of my website but Google doesn't read them.

It is a **PWA** that uses **javascript**. I think this may be the problem.

Can somebody please helps me to find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: What is "_a meta tag_"? "_Google_" here is an indexing robot? The browser? Something else? What is the actual question?

Comment: Hi Teemu. I have written "title", "description", "keywords" (I mean this for metatag) in the head of my page, but when I use Tool as SeoFrog, it doesn't see them. If I use others Tool they don't see the content of my pages. I think that this happens because Google has problems with javascript. But probably what I say isn't true. I'm not an expert, you already know it

Comment: @valentina93 Google shouldn't have problems in running JS, as it uses headless Chrome. And also I don't see how Polymer could interfere with your meta tags. But do *you* see them if you view source? And since one of the tags you list is "title": do you actually see the title in the browser's tab header?

Comment: I'd recall Google bots ignore the meta tags anyway, those were misused so badly in the past.

Comment: Hi, @mishu. I don't see the Title in the Browser's tab header. I'm going crazy, because I really want to know why happen this. Title it's important side Seo.. In the company where I'm doing my internship there isn't nobody that can help me. So I'm writing here.
thanks